# OnBackPressed with a SoftKeyboard open

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to finish an activity when the soft keyboard is open, I want to override the back event of the soft keyboard and finish the activity.

I'm using this but it's not working , any Idea ?

```
 public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            this.finish();
            return false;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`onKeyDown()` and `onBackPressed()` doesn't work for this case. You have to use `onKeyPreIme`.

Initially, you have to create custom edit text that extends `EditText`. And then you have to implement `onKeyPreIme` method which controls `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`. After this, one back press enough for solve your problem. This solution works for me perfectly.

CustomEditText.java

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    Context context;

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // User has pressed Back key. So hide the keyboard
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)         
                context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // TODO: Hide your view as you do it in your activity
        }
        return false;
}
```

In your XML

```
<com.YOURAPP.CustomEditText
     android:id="@+id/CEditText"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

In your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private CustomEditText editText;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      editText = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);
   }
}
```